# Python - How to filter list of dics based on another list of dics

Tags: python, python-2.7, filtering

can you please give me advice, how to speed up things in Python

My current issue - code works - but eat all the memory - as I have 2 included for loop (

So - I have 2 lists of dicts and need filter it based on logic below.

```
  count = 0
  size = 0
  latest = dateutil.parser.parse('1900-01-01T00:00:00.000')

  for obj_seg in objects_segments[1]:
    exclude = False
    for obj in objects[1]:
      if obj['name'] in obj_seg['name']:
        exclude = True
        break

    if not exclude:
      d = dateutil.parser.parse(obj_seg['last_modified'])
      if d > latest:
        latest = d
      size+=obj_seg['bytes']
      count+=1
```

Problem that "objects_segments[1]" can include up to 30M elements, and "objects[1]" - up to 100K...

What the better way to operate with such data without this ugly included for_loop (

**UPD1:** Change boolean logic and add break to second cycle. Tnx @nthall

Answer (score 1):

Well, one easy improvement would be to stop the inner loop after setting `exclude = False` -- right now you will continue through the loop unnecessarily.

```
for obj in objects[1]:
  if obj['name'] not in obj_seg['name']:
    exclude = False
    break
```

Comment: Tnx a lot! ) Forget about this completely

Comment: Btw - it;s not. To use break we should change logic from exclude = False inside cycle to exclude = True - in this case - yes - we can break the cycle